# Is it possible to make a patch that modifies a module's composer.json?

Tags: composer

I want to confirm some behavior of Composer to see if this is a limitation of Composer or something I did wrong.

[This is based on an issue in the Markdown module queue.](https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown/issues/3024662)

Basically, here's the issue.

1. The Markdown module requires `^0.15` of a library.
2. I wrote a patch to require `~0.15` of the library. (to allow 0.16, 0.17, etc.)

But, when I apply this patch via Composer, and then try to update the library, I still get a `drupal/markdown  1.2.0  requires  league/commonmark (^0.15.0)` even though the module's (patched) code on my site requires `~0.15`.

So, is there no way to "patch" a composer.json so that it will be picked up for `composer update`?  Am I reliant on the module maintainer to commit the patch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue is actually addressed in the [`composer-patches`](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches#patches-containing-modifications-to-composerjson-files) documentation:

> Because patching occurs after Composer calculates dependencies and installs packages, changes to an underlying dependency's composer.json file introduced in a patch will have no effect on installed packages.
>
> If you need to modify a dependency's composer.json or its underlying dependencies, you cannot use this plugin. Instead, you must do one of the following:
>
> - Work to get the underlying issue resolved in the upstream package.
> - Fork the package and specify your fork as the package repository in your root composer.json
> - Specify compatible package version requirements in your root composer.json

If you want to follow option #2, you can fork the project's git repo, modify it, and add the forked repo to your project's `repositories` property:

```
    {
        "type":"git",
        "url": "https://github.com/vendor/module"
    }
```

So you can reference that dependency until the upstream has resolved the issue.

Comment: Worth mentioning that when doing so the branch [must be prefixed `dev-`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs). No matter how its actual name is. After you added the repository your custom branch should appear prefixed with `dev-` prefix when executing `$ composer show "vendor/module" --all`.